# Why does Redshift always do a seq scan, even with a sort key?

Tags: performance, amazon-redshift

I have what seems to be a pretty simple scenario but for some reason my query always does a seq scan and doesn't use the sortkey defined for the table.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE md_event_time between '2017-07-23 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-27 23:59:00'
```

The field in the where clause is showing up as the sortkey in the table info.
Explain:

```
XN Seq Scan on table1 (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=20) 
Filter: ((md_event_time <= '2017-07-27 23:59:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND 
(md_event_time >= '2017-07-23 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is the time column the first column of the sort key? have you run vacuum/analyse on the table? how many rows does the table have?

Comment: This is a single sort key.  I have run vacuum/analyze.  The count is 483 million rows.

Comment: is the data type of the column `timestamp without timezone`? is it compressed?

Comment: The datatype is timestamp and it's encoded with zstd.

Comment: the problem might be the encoding

Comment: My apologies the encoding was delta32k, however I removed the encoding to just use raw and still not utilizing the sort key.

Comment: can you check the query execution time both for a table with compressed column and with uncompressed?

Comment: Not much of a difference between compressed and uncompressed query times. 11sec uncompressed 11.2 compressed.

Comment: weird... is there a dist key on the table?

Comment: Yes. There is a dist key.

Comment: what is its cardinality? like what is the N of unique values vs. total row count

Comment: `SELECT *` is an anti-pattern for Redshift (and any columnar database) because it forces the database to do a lot of extra work. Try a simple aggregate to see the difference. `SELECT md_event_time::DATE, COUNT(*) rows FROM table1 WHERE md_event_time between '2017-07-23 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-27 23:59:00' GROUP BY 1;`

Answer (score 5):

You can't see the effect of the sort key in the `EXPLAIN` plan. Run the query and then look for it in the `SVL_QUERY_SUMMARY` view, specifically look for the column `is_rrscan` equal to `t` on the row that shows a scan of the table. This indicates that Redshift was able to reduce the scan by using the sort key range.

If there is a large difference between the `rows_pre_filter` and `rows` counts then make sure the table is `VACUUM`ed (to removed deleted rows) and then **consider removing compression from the first sort key only** by setting it to `ENCODE raw` (too much compression on the sort key forces the DB to materialize too many rows).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVL_QUERY_SUMMARY.html

Comment: Good to know. I will remove the compression and see how well it performs.

I found the query in the svl_query_report view and is_rsscan is true.  It was able to limit the scan to 38 million rows instead of 445million.

Comment: I was kind of skeptical of not seeing the sort key in the explain plan, so I loaded another table with the same data without a sort key.  The SVL_QUERY_REPORT still shows is_rsscan as true because it's doing a range restriction not necessarily because it is using the sort key.

Comment: That's true. It is not set *only* for sort key usage. It will be set any time Redshift can use the block min/max value range to eliminate reads. If the data is loaded in roughly the same order as the sort key then Redshift can still do an effective range restricted scan. Reload the data in a random order without a sort key (e.g. `ORDER BY random()`) to see the effect more clearly.

Comment: Reinserted data and did order_by random() , is_rsscan still shows as true.  Same performance as before.

Comment: @JoeHarris, why would compression on the sort key force materialization of rows?  wouldn't only the sort key col(s) need to be materialized?

Comment: @JoeHarris I don't understand the difference, how much is big? For example, the difference between rows_pre_filter and rows? for us is 111516 records.

Comment: I believe `is_rrscan` just indicates that your query has _any_ range predicate regardless of whether its related to the sort key or not